# Android studio некорректно отображает исходники

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle

В один прекрасный день открываю проект в *Android Studio 3.4*, а там *R* класс не сгенерировался. Ну, думаю, бывает. Пробую *Clean Project, Rebuild Project, Sync Project with Gradle Files, Sync with File System, Invalidate Caches and Restart,* но они не помогают. Как и ручное удаление папок *.idea* и *build*.

Затем полез в *AndroidManifest.xml*, а там какая-то каша - вместо манифеста куски из *gradle.build*, а в *gradle.build* куски кода из файлов автогенерации... К ужасу обнаружил, что в исходниках посреди кода также присутствуют куски кода из других *gradle* файлов.

Ужас ушел, когда я посмотрел исходники через блокнот - там все чисто и на месте.

Переустановка Студии не помогает, как и отключение всевозможных плагинов. В IntelliJ IDEA полет нормальный.

Стало очень интересно, что приключилось со Студией, и как это исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Andrew Goroshko за ссылку: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54509482/10563474. Помог ответ Hong'a:

> Delete the caches folder:
>   C:\Users\my_user_name.AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches

Comment: Кажется, подобная штука происходит, когда компьютер переходит в спящий режим с открытой студией. После отключения оного таких проблем больше не наблюдалось.